# Implementation of RFB protocol

Tags: api, rfb-protocol

I am looking for an Implementation of the `RFB protocol` to use it in my project, after a long search about it, I came across this [topic](http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/894766-implementation-rfb-protocol) (the answer is written by an expert member ...) I already posted a topic on another forum and I had the same answer.

My question is: Why we call it `RFB protocol` and there is not an API or a library that implement it?
For my knowledge, a protocol should have an API to use it; such as TCP / IP, UDP...

PS: Another question posted by me about same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300429/use-the-source-code-of-tightvnc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A protocol needs only a description to be called a protocol. For example, the [HTTP/1.1 protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) is documented in the form of an RFC, which is just text. There is absolutely no discussion of programming languages or APIs or libraries in the protocol description. It is up to different authors to provide APIs, and this encourages wildly different implementations such as [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630(v=vs.85).aspx), [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), and [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

Similarly, the RFB *protocol* is just a description of how two software components talk to each other and exchange frame buffer information. The existence of a protocol description does *not* imply that there must necessarily be an API or library for your chosen programming language.